# Parsec trouble with end of line

Tags: haskell, parsec

I've got a Parsec parser that I'm writing in mostly applicative style. In one case (the only time I'm using `sepBy`) I'm having trouble with my `eol` parser. First, a few definitions:

```
eol =   try (string "\n\r")
    <|> try (string "\r\n")
    <|> string "\n"
    <|> string "\r"
    <?> "eol"

betaLine = string "BETA " *> (StrandPair <$> p_int <*> p_int <*> p_int <*> (p_int *> p_direction) <*> p_exposure) <* eol
```

Note: `betaLine` works perfectly (for brevity, I've left out the definitions of `p_int` and such:

```
*HmmPlus> parse betaLine "beta" "BETA 6 11 5 24 -1 oiiio\n"
Right (StrandPair {firstStart = 6, secondStart = 11, pairLength = 5, parallel =   Antiparallel, exposure = [Exposed,Buried,Buried,Buried,Exposed]})
```

The problem occurs with this other parser, `hmmMatchEmissions`:

```
 hmmMatchEmissions     = spaces *> (V.fromList <$> sepBy p_logProb spaces) <* eol <?> "matchEmissions"

*HmmPlus> parse hmmMatchEmissions "me" "      2.61196  4.43481  2.86148  2.75135  3.26990  2.87580  3.69681\n"
Left "me" (line 2, column 1):
unexpected end of input
```

Now, if I remove the `<* eol` from the parser definition, and remove the `\n` from the line, it does work:

```
*HmmPlus> parse hmmMatchEmissions "me" "      2.61196  4.43481  2.86148  2.75135  3.26990  2.87580  3.69681"
Right (fromList [NonZero 2.61196,NonZero 4.43481,NonZero 2.86148,NonZero 2.75135,NonZero 3.2699,NonZero 2.8758,NonZero 3.69681])
```

So, why is `eol` working in the case of `betaLine` but not `hmmMatchEmissions`?

I will note that this is the only place I'm using `sepBy`; could that be a clue?

Update: I've done the following, and it now fails differently :/

```
reqSpaces = many1 (oneOf " \t")

optSpaces = many (oneOf " \t")

hmmMatchEmissions = optSpaces *> (V.fromList <$> sepBy1 p_logProb reqSpaces) <* eol <?> "matchEmissions"
```

And here's the failure:

```
*HmmPlus> parse hmmMatchEmissions "me" "  0.123  0.124\n"
Left "me" (line 1, column 10):
unexpected "0"
expecting eol
```

I'll note that the unexpected `0` in column 10 is the first character of the `0.124` token.

Comment: A guess: it's `spaces` that's giving you trouble, not `sepBy` per se. Try using `spaces` definition that excludes newline characters.

Comment: I've tried this, which produces a different failure mode... see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `p_logProb` parser consumes whitespace. So, this is what happens during the parse:

```
  0.123  0.124\n
[]               optSpaces
  [-----]        p_logProb
         {       trying reqSpaces
         {       trying eol
                 failure: expecting eol
```

The `p_logProb` parser should only consume the thing that it parses, namely the actual number. This will lead to the intended parse:

```
  0.123  0.124\n
[]               optSpaces
  [---]          p_logProb
       []        reqSpaces
         [---]   p_logProb
              {  trying reqSpaces
              #  eol
```

Comment: Is your answer the result of some debugging system?  I struggle with Parsec every time I use it because the error result is so uninformative, and I frequently just switch back to parsing directly.

Comment: No, I wrote those graphs manually. However, if you have trouble using Parsec, you should probably simplify your grammar, because that's probably where the real problem is!